# Unable to serialize the session state, which is related to System.Data.Linq. EntitySet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, serialization, session-state, entityset

Recently I am playing with the Windows Server 2008,
and would like to make some configuration for my web application.
I have changed the Session State for my application to "State Server" so it can make use of more work process (Now it is set to 4).

Afterwards I have got this error when I attempt to login to the application.

**Unable to serialize the session state**. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.

I suspect it is related to the EntitySet I have declared because I see this in the Stack Trace when the error occur:

> [SerializationException: Type
>   'System.Data.Linq.EntityRef`1[[CtcSystem.Domain.Entities.Account.Account,
>   CtcSystem.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]' in Assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as
>   serializable.]

I have used **[Serializable]** tag on my classes,
so is there any way I have to do to make the EntitySet serializable so that the application can run under State Server?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate : [are-linq-to-sql-objects-serializable-for-session-state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643793/are-linq-to-sql-objects-serializable-for-session-state)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to implement the ISerializable interface on a partial class...